# Why is PHP and MySQL script not working on a Raspberry Pi server?

Tags: php, mysql, raspberry-pi

I am running Debian 7 (Wheezy), release 7.8 on my Raspberry Pi. I have got Apache 2 installed with PHP (version 5.4) and MySQL (version 5.5) installed as my server. A simpe PHP script with some HTML works as expected.

However PHP scripts with database query do not work on my Raspberry Pi server. For example, upon submission of a form, the page just refreshes resetting the form, but it does not seem to perform the SQL query at all. When I test the same scripts on my PC using [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP), the script seems to work well.

Why does this happen? Do I need to make any modification to the PHP script before uploading it onto my Raspberry Pi server (Linux-based) servers?

I have got the `display_errors` feature enabled on my Raspberry Pi Web server, but I cannot see any error messages.

#### HTML/PHP

```
<?php
    # mysqli_connect.php

    // This file contains the database access information.
    /* This file also establishes a connection to MySQL, selects the
    database and sets the encoding.*/

    // Set the database access information as
    // constants:
    //
    //     DEFINE('DB_USER', 'root');
    //     DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
    //     DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    //     DEFINE('DB_NAME', 'test_db');

    // Make the connections:
    $dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR
        die ('Could not connect to MYSQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() ); ?>
```

The query is:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, country, biography, registration_date) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$country', '$biography', NOW() )"; aaaaaa

$r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
```

I am able to connect to MySQL from the command line on the Raspberry Pi. The table exists in the MySQL database, and I am using the 'root' user, which has the right user privilege. The PHP extension was mysqli.

I had the same issue when trying to set up WordPress on my Raspberry Pi. The set up PHP script failed to execute properly.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com: I don't think this is necessarily off topic.  The question doesn't contain enough information currently, but it certainly falls under "software tools commonly used by programmers"

Comment: Have you tried a simple test like `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>`. A form not submitting can have numerous causes.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com opinion based questions are _very_ poor fit for Programmers - these are typically quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: yes, I have tried `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>`. it works fine.

Comment: Would you please post code for the database connection and query so we know how you are connecting and what MySQL library you are using?  Are you able to connect to mysql from the command line on the RPi, database and tables exist and the connecting user has access?

Comment: <?php # mysqli_connect.php
    // This file contains the database access information.
    /* This file also establishes a connection to MySQL, 
    selects the database and sets the encoding.*/


    // Set the database access information as constants:
    DEFINE('DB_USER', 'root');
    DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
    DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    DEFINE('DB_NAME', 'test_db');

    // Make the connections:
    $dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not connect to MYSQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );
?>

Comment: **The query is:**
$q = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, country, biography, registration_date) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$country', '$biography', NOW() )";
    $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

Comment: And yes, I am able to connect to MySQL from the command line on the RPi. The exists in the MySQL database and I am using the 'root' user, which has the right user privilege. The PHP extension was mysqli.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that I had the same issue when trying to set up WordPress on my RPi. The set up php script failed to execute properly.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I had exactly the same experience.